# Can I respec my Dead Island character?

Tags: dead-island

After finally getting the game set up how I want it to run, I've started playing with Xian as my main character. I've now earned enough XP to level up, but I'm wondering if I will have the ability to respec my character. I chose to learn "Fury" as my first skill to see if any option to reset my skill choice appeared after the fact, but I do not see one in the menu.

Does respeccing exist in this game? If so, how/when do I get the ability to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is currently no way of respeccing a Dead Island character.

Comment: Argh, that was definitely not the answer I was hoping for...

Comment: Not surprised given other things pulled in that game. No respeccing, quest data is overwritten any time you join another player, and enemies don't even scale when more players join. Dead Island is so Borderlands-esque but they learned nothing from them ...

Comment: That is wrong. Enemies are scaled at the level of the host. Quest data is not overwriten if you joinsomeone way ahead of you their completed quest will be completed for you but when you go back to your save anyquest that you didt have and complete will still be there, but if you have lets say the quest (SMALL SPOILER) "nighthawk" and find the crashe plane and tell the old hag what happend then you will get the reward there and it will be completed in your save.

Comment: After I realized they accidentally released a dev version of the game I understand why so much was broken when I played it ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Dead Island Save Editor](http://deadislandsaveeditor.blogspot.ru/) if you're on PC or Xbox 360. Open a save, go to Skills and hit Reset, then Save and Sync Now through the menu. When you load that save, you will have 0 skills and the appropriate number of skill points for your level (the game is surprisingly clever about this).

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough question, because there are interpretations that stretch the concept of respec. In short, no, there is no respec option.

A close thing: From the title menu, click PLAY, then new game (top), pick the character that you want to respec, default player setup, and the last chapter available. E.g, at chapter 18, the game generates a character with a crowbar and machete, both white-rarity, $10000, at level 32, and with no skill points spent.

What if, instead of choosing "default player setup", I choose a character save file? This creates a new save. The new save will use the chosen character data. The character will be set at the chosen chapter's story progress. This does not affect items, skill-points, side-quests from before the story point, blueprints acquired, etc..

If you are not opposed to the use of exploits to regain lost progress in the face of the lack of a better respec system, grinding levels is easy Sveti with the Time for Booze continuous event (side-quest), with duplication.