# How many total skill points does a character get in Dead Island?

Tags: dead-island

Considering there is [no respec mechanism](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29987/can-i-respec-my-dead-island-character) in Dead Island, I'm trying to plan out my character build a little in advance.

In examining the skill tree I see there are:

- 21 possible points in Fury
- 39 possible points in Combat
- 39 possible points in Survival

I am assuming that all characters have the same number of points to put in their tree (I'm currently playing Xian). Judging from the achievements, the current level cap in-game is 60, but I don't know if there may be instances where you level up and get 2 upgrades available or something.

So how many total skill points can a level 60 character have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no other way of gaining skill points other than leveling up, which only grants one skill point.

So the amount of skill points you would have at level 60 would be 59.

Comment: So that means, like in borderlands, you can't fully upgrade your skills ?

Comment: @Chuck - unless they do the same thing as borderlands and increase the level cap though a dlc or a patch, mordi2k is right

Comment: @graven, and even with the new level cap, you're still restricted to a single skill point per level ... you just get 10 more of them. So it's still not possible to max out a character.