# What's the maximum level in Dead Island?

Tags: dead-island

What's the maximum level in Dead Island that you can reach and does it make in sort that you can have max-out skills ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The current maximum level in Dead Island is **60**, which means you can only get **59** skill points.

[Related to skill points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30002/how-many-total-skill-points-does-a-character-get-in-dead-island/30006#30006)

Comment: I was playing with a level 72 earlier today in the prison ?

Comment: @user23269 Maybe he was using [modified files](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2124964)?

Answer (score 2):

As of the [November 11th, 2011 update](http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/718242/dead-island-console-patch-ups-level-cap-adds-weapon-mods/), the level cap is now **60**.

Comment: You can get higher than 60. I haven't cheated or hacked the game, and I'm now at level 67.